# Crash issue on Google Play Pre-Launch Report : java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, google-play, google-play-services

I have Add my App to Pre-launch report it throws some error like

```
`Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: AppSearchBatchResult has failures: {
  successes: {}
  failures: {https://g.co/pixeltips/tips_livetranslate_messaging?LaunchFrom=APP_SEARCH=[FAILURE(6)]: Schema type config 'com.google.android.apps.tips$/Tip' not found}
}
  at androidx.a.a.b.a (AppSearchBatchResult.java:1)
  at com.google.android.apps.tips.search.platform.a.d (PlatformIndex.java:11)
  at com.google.android.apps.tips.search.b.a (TipsIndexingHelper.java:20)
  at com.google.android.apps.tips.search.d.run (TipsIndexingJobService.java:1)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:920)`
```

What is the problem in it?

Can anyone help me to solve this.

I didn't rectify the problem where it occured.

Comment: Seeing the same today. Did you ever find a solution?